# create new list based on matching two keys

Tags: python

Given y lists with x dictionaries as their elements, I would like to produce a new list, with a joined set of dictionaries. Each dictionary is guaranteed to have a key called "homeworld" and a key called "name", but could have an arbitrary set of keys beyond that. For example, imagine the following two lists:

```
list1 = [{"name": "Leia Organa", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"}, 
{"name": "C-3PO", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"}, 
{"name": "Bail Prestor Organa", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"}, 
{"name": "Luke Skywalker", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"}]

list2 = [{"name": "Alderaan", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"},
{"name": "Yavin IV", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/3/"}, 
{"name": "Tatooine", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"}]
```

Based on the keys list1['homeworld'] and list2['url'],
I would like to produce a joined list:

```
list3 = [
{"name": "Alderaan", "persons": ["Leia Organa", "Bail Prestor Organa"]},
{"name": "Tatooine", "persons": ["Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO"]}
]
```

What is the best way to do this in Python?

WHAT I'VE tried so far...

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = get_planets()['results']
l2 = get_people()['results']

d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in (l1, l2):           <-----is this even set up correctly?
    for elem in l:
        # how to write this here? if l2['homeworld'] == l1['url']: ???
            d[elem['name']].update(elem)  <---not sure what goes here
l3 = d.values()
```

Comment: Worry about how to do it *at all* before you worry about the best way. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried a few different variations...I've updated question with my recent attempt...Note get_planets and get_people grab the json results from swapi .. https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=1  and https://swapi.co/api/people/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehensions:

```
list1 = [{"name": "Leia Organa", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"}, 
         {"name": "C-3PO", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"}, 
         {"name": "Bail Prestor Organa", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"}, 
         {"name": "Luke Skywalker", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"}]

list2 = [{"name": "Alderaan", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"},
         {"name": "Yavin IV", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/3/"}, 
         {"name": "Tatooine", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"}]

list3 = [{'name': x['name'], 'persons': [y['name'] for y in list1 if y['homeworld'] == x['url']]} for x in list2]

list3 = [x for x in list3 if x['persons']]

print(list3)
# [{'name': 'Alderaan', 'persons': ['Leia Organa', 'Bail Prestor Organa']}, 
#  {'name': 'Tatooine', 'persons': ['C-3PO', 'Luke Skywalker']}]
```